# How can I confirm I've "maintained" a Salesforce certification?

Tags: certification

I took a trailhead module to maintain a Salesforce certification, but I don't know for sure that the certification is "maintained". I linked my WebAccessor account with Trailhead before completing the maintenance module, but I haven't received any confirmation my certification will still be current as of tomorrow. Today is the deadline for maintaining the certification. My certification isn't found I try to verify it using my name or email address.

Comment: Are you verifying with your WebAssessor email address?

Comment: In my experience, confirmation email took time to arrive when I completed the trailmix for maintenance release. Lookout for a confirmation email in few days. As long as you have your trailhead and webassessor accounts linked, you should be fine.

Comment: Have you [connected your trailhead to the webaccessor](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/connect-webassessor?lang=en) ?

Answer (score 1):

https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/credentials/verification

Try the above link. You can search by your name or email and it should tell you what certs are live for you.

Comment: Nothing found when I search my name or email. I mentioned that.

Comment: In that case I think you may be best off contacting salesforce support directly.. not sure there is really another way to find that info.

Comment: The verification page hasn't been working for the past couple of days.  Scared the heck out of me when I saw that none of my certs were showing up!  I submitted a case.

Answer (score 1):

You can see the status in the below link.
https://trailblazer.me/

Please note that it will take one business day to update the status once you have completed the module.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can login to [Webassesor](https://www.webassessor.com/)  and have a look at your list of Completed Exams. The maintenance exams done on Trailhead will show up there eventually:

[image: Maintenance Exams]

As an additional note to using https://trailhead.salesforce.com/credentials/verification to verify your credentials: If you're using the 'Verify a Salesforce Certified Professional' to search on your full name or email address, you need to optin for this verification in your Webassessor profile before anything will show up.
I think the 'Certification Holders: Check your Status' doesn't require this, but you of course need to use the email address that you use for your Webassessor account.

Answer (score 0):

This question surfaced top of my search results, so though it is an old thread updating with latest information which helped me figure out my certification credentials status w.r.t pending maintenance exams.
https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000332910&type=1

You would then receive an email something like this
[image]